# In Codeigniter, how to pass a third parameter to a callback (form validation)?

Tags: codeigniter, callback, validation, codeigniter-2, validationrules

I am currently using the Form Validation class (on Codeigniter) and setting rules.

It works like this with two parameters ([codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_test[abc]');
```

But what about a third parameter? And a fourth...? Is it possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not official but works

Split the parameter by ','

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('article_big_image','Gambar Besar','callback_check_picture[article_big_image,edit]');

function check_picture($image,$param){
    $param = preg_split('/,/', $param);
    $field = $param[0];
    $action = $param[1];
    echo $field.$action;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without extended the system form validation class.  For information on how to achieve this take a look at this [article](http://www.robertmullaney.com/2010/11/04/codeigniter-form-validation-callback-functions-with-multiple-arguments/).

Alternatively you can access the post variables within your callback function using:

```
$this->input->post('field_name');
```

which may or may not help you out.

Comment: Thanks it should work (I will try it later) but a bit disappointed to learn there is no easy way to do that like `callback_test[abc,def,ghi]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array for more parameters for more fields as like i did below:

```
 $error = array(

                array(
                'field' => 'check', // the field name will come here
                'label' => 'Check',
                'rules' => 'required|here you can put the callback Function'
                )
          );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('article_big_image','Gambar','callback_check_picture[article_big_image,edit]');
    function check_picture($image,$param){
        $param = explode(',', $param);
        $field = isset($param[0])?$param[0]:'';
        $action = isset($param[1])?$param[1]:'';
       echo $field.$action;
   }
```

Comment: You can edit the other answer instead of posting a separate answer, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass to the rule
`|callback_handle_is_unique_value_combinations[val1,val2]`

than,
 `public function callback_handle_is_unique_value_combinations($str, $field)
    {
        $fields = explode(',', $field);
        $val1 = $fields[0];
        $val2 = $fields[1];`

and then you made your cponarisons