# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Email.(validate_credentials)

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, callback, codeigniter-3

I'm using a `form_validation` in my CI application and while using a `callback function` in `set_rules()` I got an error:

> Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name
>   Email.(validate_credentials)

My Controller code is:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends MX_Controller 
{
    // public function __construct()
    // {
    //  parent::__construct();
    // }

    // public function index()
    // {
    //  $this->load->view('auth/login_v');
    // }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('auth/login_v');
    }

    public function login_validation()
    {
        //$this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|callback_validate_credentials');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            redirect('dashboard');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('auth/login_v');
        }

        //echo $this->input->post('email');
    }

    public function validate_credentials()
    {
        $this->load->model('Auth_model');

        if($this->Auth_model->can_log_in())
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials', 'Incorrect Email/Password');

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know where am I mistaking.
I had pass the parameters to tha callback function:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|callback_validate_credentials[email]');
```

and

```
public function validate_credentials($email)
    {
        $this->load->model('Auth_model');
```

but I got same error.

I have referred following sites:

[In Codeigniter, how to pass a third parameter to a callback (form validation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740973/in-codeigniter-how-to-pass-a-third-parameter-to-a-callback-form-validation)

[Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613010/unable-to-access-an-error-message-corresponding-to-your-field-name)

[Callback function in Codeigniter with multiple parameters during form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324420/callback-function-in-codeigniter-with-multiple-parameters-during-form-validation)

[CodeIgniter callback functions with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261177/codeigniter-callback-functions-with-parameters)

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

[CodeIgniter - Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(pword_check)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665715/codeigniter-unable-to-access-an-error-message-corresponding-to-your-field-name)

[Callback Function Error ( Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746744/callback-function-error-unable-to-access-an-error-message-corresponding-to-you)

I'm using codeigniter 3.1.6 and HMVC for my application.

Any kind of help will always welcome. Thanks

Comment: Load this this->load->library('form_validation') in the __construct area of controller https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Comment: I've already loaded form_validation library in my autoload.php file. Steel I've to load it in my __construct() function ?

Comment: Same error. No any effect after: public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
 }

Comment: Also just a tip don't use md5 for passwords as very unsecure for passwords  you should hash with this http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and then verify with this http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: in your calback you need to get a parameter like `public function validate_credentials( $str = '')` called with this `$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|callback_validate_credentials');`

Comment: I suspect your beloved HMVC is causing your problems. See: https://github.com/krishnabhat81/Codeigniter-HMVC-form-validation-callback-not-working

Comment: @BrianGottier actually I already go for that, but when I'm extending the class in library, it give an error. First I'm extending class CI_Form_validation and then made a changes to MX_Form_validation. Both gives errors. Will you please give the sample code for library class.

Comment: Inside set_rule callback, do not pass the parameter. i.e. $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|callback_validate_credentials');

Pass the argument in the function declaration. i.e. public function validate_credentials($email). Take look in CI documentation of callback. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods